# Handling hash function Insertio into MySql Database via Visual Studio C# .NET

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, hash

I am working on a login system for a giant company with a hotel, restaurant and pool.
Each Employee within this company will have access/+monitoring credentials to the system's DB.

I understand saving passwords in plain text is a **BAD BAD** approach so I managed the password hashing part tested it using text boxes and Message Boxes(which I removed later). and since almost everyone (or the post, videos and threads/forms I've read) said it is a must to have a `HashFunction` and a `Salt` Column in your database beside the `HashedPassword` Column; I am having some of a *hard-time* inserting the hash-function value into the `HashFunction` column for I don't know what is the value that holds it!

Here is the code I have

```
private MySqlConnection Connect()
    {
        string con = "Server = servername; DataBase=DBName; username= usr; password=pwd ; Persist Security Info = False; Charset =utf8";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(con);
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }
    private String Salt(int size)
    {
        var rng = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        var buffsize = new byte[size];
        rng.GetBytes(buffsize);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(buffsize);
    }

    private String GenerateSHA256Hash(string In, string salt)
    {
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(In + salt);
        SHA256Managed sha256hashstring = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] hash = sha256hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }

    private void BtnAddUsr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string salt = Salt(10);
        string hashedpswd = GenerateSHA256Hash(text.Text, salt);
        string AddUser = "Insert into users(name,password,hashedpass,salt,position) VALUES ('" + txtu.Text + "','" + txtp.Text + "','" + hashedpswd.ToString() + "',";
    }
```

How I can handle this and if by any chance anyone can help me with verifying if the user enters the right password, it would be great?
Many Thanks.

Comment: The HashFunc should store the value which can indicate what hashing algorithm you have used for particular password. Such as SHA-256, SHA-512 etc... You use this value to decide the hashing algorithm when user logs in.

Comment: You don't need password column in the table because you are not going to store the plain text password in it

Comment: @Chetan I meant by password column the hashed one, that's why you saw the hash function... now that you *You don't need password column in the table because you are not going to store the plain text password in it* it hit my mind i need to drop either the hashfunc or password column, although i am still confused about authenticating the password, should i compare the output of `GenerateSHA256Hash` method to that stored in the db?

Comment: Yes you need to get check if the user exist or not based on username.. if yes then get the salt of the user and generate the hash of the password entered by the user and compare it with the hashed password stored in the db for the user. If the hash matches the password is correct.

Comment: @Chetan thank you, man. you saved me a lot of headache

Comment: Don't roll your own authentication system.

Comment: @CodeCaster I will remove the pics and the part of the code that has sensitive details. although those can be easily changed. thanks for the warning tho :)

Comment: I'm not talking about sensitive details? I mean that this code and this database design should not be something that you implement yourself, because you're bound to do things wrong, impacting your users' security. Use an existing authentication framework that has already solved this problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster would you like to aid me in applying Bcrypt to my project?

I have tested this approach on several hundred users added and the login was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Chetan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884101/chetan) I have managed to figure out where I messed up **BIG TIME**!!!

The code looks pretty much the same except for minor stupid changes in the `command string`

```
    private void BtnAddUsr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
         {
            if (txtp.Text != "" && txtu.Text != "")
            {
                MySqlConnection con = Connect();
                string salt = Salt(10);
                string hashedpswd = GenerateSHA256Hash(txtp.Text, salt);
                string AddUser = "Insert into users(name,hashedpass,salt,position) VALUES (@username,@hashedpassword,@salt,@poz)";
                MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(AddUser, con);
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", txtu.Text);
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hashedpass", hashedpswd);
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sugar", salt);
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@poz", CmbPositions.SelectedItem.ToString());


                //'" + txtu.Text + "','" + hashedpswd.ToString() + "', '"+hashvalue.ToString()+"', " +
                //"'" + salt.ToString() + "','" + CmbPositions.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'
                int res = mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (res == 1)
                {
                    DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("User Added Successfully,Would you like to sing-in?", "Proceed?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        new Thread(() => new Form1().ShowDialog()).Start();
                        this.SendToBack();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Application.Exit();
                    }
                }
            }
         }
         catch (MySqlException ex)
         {
             if (txtp.Text == "" || txtu.Text == "")
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Adding User", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
             }
         }
         finally
         {
             Connect().Close();
         }
    }
```

Comment: You should look at a bcyrpt nuget package, which will do most of this for you and help you avoid the kind of mistake where a year down the road you find out you were hacked six months ago.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, so basically BlowFish is better and way safer and when it comes to applying this algorithm it is the same as SHA256 and any other encryption when it comes to coding right?